# Typescript Unions interface and primitive

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings

Condidering this example

```
interface fooInterface {
    bar: any;
}
function(value: fooInterface | string) { 
    value.bar 
}
```

The error is: Property 'bar' does not exist on type '(fooInterface | string)'

I'm doing something wrong obviously. What I want to say basically is: value is EITHER an object implementing fooInterface or a string.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Yes union type is the right way to say that. But if it's a string, it won't have `bar` property, so it's an error to access it like that. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If you are conviced that value contains fooInterface value, you can convince TypeScript of your truth by `(<fooInterface>value).bar` or `(value as fooInterface).bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `value.bar` because it's not *definitely* safe. It might be safe (because value might be a string), but the compiler doesn't know that for sure, and it won't let you do `.bar` unless it's sure. What you probably want to do is use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types):

```
if (typeof value !== "string") {
    value.bar
   // This compiles happily, because inside this if, value has
   // type 'fooInterface'. That's because TS now knows it isn't a string,
   // so *must* be a fooInterface.
}
```

You can play around with this [in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20fooInterface%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20f(value%3A%20fooInterface%20%7C%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20value%20!%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value.bar%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value.bar%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%0A%7D): notice that only one of the `value.bar`'s fails, because it knows that only that one is wrong.

If you can't/don't want to do this you can instead just tell the compiler you know what you're doing with a type assertion (e.g. `var definitelyFoo = <fooInterface> value`), but a guard is usually the better choice.

Comment: Makes sense, it forces my code to be more robust, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If, you are telling that `value` is either of type `fooInterface` or `string`, you have to check the type before you can work with the `value`. In your case you simply check whether `value` is `string` using `typeof`. If not, it is `fooInterface`.

```
interface fooInterface {
    bar: any;
}
function(value: fooInterface | string) {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        // The compiler now knows that value is string
    }
    else {
        /* The compiler is smart and knows that the value
           must be of type fooInterface. */

        value.bar 
    }
}
```

In other cases you would have to use [`instanceof`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) (for checking whether object is typeof specific class) or your [own type checks](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) (if there were multiple interfaces or custom types).